# Adding a string onto each item in a list using functions

Tags: python

So, my teacher wants me to make a program using two functions to add "Hall of Famer" to each baseball player in a list. We're supposed to start with this program that prints the name of each of the players on the list:

```
def show_players(players):
    """Show list of baseball players"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.title())

baseball_players = ['jackie robinson', 'babe ruth', 'barry bonds']
show_players(baseball_players)
```

We have to write another function that adds "Hall of Famer" to each of the players, this is what I've got (it doesn't work how I'd like it to):

```
def show_players(players):
    """Show list of baseball players"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.title())

def make_HOF(baseball_players):
    """Make each baseball player a Hall of Famer"""
    HOF = "Hall of Famer "
    for player in baseball_players:
        HOF_players = [HOF + player]
    return HOF_players  

HOF_players = []        
baseball_players = ['jackie robinson', 'babe ruth', 'barry bonds']
make_HOF(baseball_players)
show_players(HOF_players)
```

Comment: [String Concatenation and Formatting](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

when you put HOF_players = [HOF + player],it's not adding anything to your list, and it is adding string and a list which doesn't achieve what you are expecting. Try HOF_players.append(HOF + player) so it adds the string 'Hall of Famer', to the string baseball_players[players] and adds it to the list.

```
def show_players(players):
    """Show list of baseball players"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.title())

baseball_players = ['jackie robinson', 'babe ruth', 'barry bonds']
show_players(baseball_players)

def make_HOF(baseball_players):
        """Make each baseball player a Hall of Famer"""
        HOF = "Hall of Famer "
        for player in baseball_players:
           HOF_players.append(HOF + player)
    return HOF_players  

HOF_players = [] 
make_HOF(baseball_players)
show_players(HOF_players)
```

if the problem fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own!

```
def show_players(players):
    """Show list of baseball players"""
    for player in players:
        print(player.title())

def make_HOF(titless_players):
    """Make each baseball player a Hall of Famer"""
    for player in titless_players:
        player = "Hall of Famer: " + player
        HOF_players.append(player)
    return HOF_players

HOF_players = []        
baseball_players = ['jackie robinson', 'babe ruth', 'barry bonds']
make_HOF(baseball_players)
show_players(HOF_players)
```

It outputs:
Hall Of Famer: Jackie Robinson
Hall Of Famer: Babe Ruth
Hall Of Famer: Barry Bonds

..which is exactly what I wanted it to do! Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're doing something to each element of a list, you should think of this as applying a map function over the list. In this case your map function is prepending the string `"Hall of Famer "` to each string in your list.

There are two (well, three...) ways to write a simple map in Python. One is by using a for loop

```
new_xs = []
for x in xs:
    new_xs.append(your_func(x))
```

Another, and much preferred, is to use a list comprehension

```
new_xs = [your_func(x) for x in xs]
```

The parenthetical third, above, is actually using the built-in `map`, which has fallen out of favor since list comprehensions are so much easier to write and read.

```
new_xs = list(map(your_func, xs))
# N.B. if you don't need this as an actual list, just something you can iterate over
# you can leave out the list(...) call.
```

In your example `your_func` should look like:

```
def add_HOF(s):  # mapping function
    return "Hall of Famer " + s
```

which is easy enough to write in-line, especially as a list comprehension

```
def add_HOFs(players):
    return ["Hall of Famer " + player.title() for player in players]
```